# Continue to get errors when working with images in PIL (Python)

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I've looked around for some solution yet have yet to find any.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

img_array = []
e = 0
year = 2010
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
for e in range(0, 11):
    year = 2010 + e
    print(e)
    print(year)
    img = cv2.imread('./pics/' + str(year) + '.jpg')
    img = cv2.putText(img, str(year), (100, 100), font, 1, (255, 255, 255), 1)
    height, width, layers = img.shape
    size = (width, height)
    img_array.append(img)
img = cv2.imread('./pics/' + "2010" + '.jpg')
img = cv2.putText(img, '2010', (100, 100), font, 1, (255, 255, 255), 1)
height, width, layers = img.shape
size = (width, height)
img_array.append(img)
img = cv2.imread('./pics/' + "2020" + '.jpg')
img = cv2.putText(img, str(year), (100, 100), font, 1, (255, 255, 255), 1)
height, width, layers = img.shape
size = (width, height)
img_array.append(img)


def getVid():
    out = cv2.VideoWriter('data.avi', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'), 0.5, size)
    for i in range(len(img_array)):
        out.write(img_array[i])
    out.release()
    print("released")


def getImage():
    left = 5
    top = height / 4
    right = 164
    bottom = 3 * height / 4
    for i in range(10, 20):
        imname = cv2.imread("~/PycharmProjects/iceSnowComparison/pics/" + '20' + str(i) + '.jpg')
        ph = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imname)
        window_name = 'image'
        cv2.imshow(window_name, ph)

   
   
# For later
    # im1 = imname.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
    # im1.save("~/PycharmProjects/iceSnowComparison/croppedpics/" + str(year) + '.jpg')
getVid()
getImage()
```

Error:

```
  File "/Users/charliesimons/PycharmProjects/iceSnowComparison/main.py", line 58, in <module>
    getImage()
  File "/Users/charliesimons/PycharmProjects/iceSnowComparison/main.py", line 48, in getImage
    ph = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imname)
  File "/Users/charliesimons/PycharmProjects/iceSnowComparison/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/ImageTk.py", line 108, in __init__
    mode = Image.getmodebase(mode)
  File "/Users/charliesimons/PycharmProjects/iceSnowComparison/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 289, in getmodebase
    return ImageMode.getmode(mode).basemode
  File "/Users/charliesimons/PycharmProjects/iceSnowComparison/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/ImageMode.py", line 74, in getmode
    return _modes[mode]
KeyError: None
Exception ignored in: <function PhotoImage.__del__ at 0x7fe6f56e58b0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/charliesimons/PycharmProjects/iceSnowComparison/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/ImageTk.py", line 118, in __del__
    name = self.__photo.name
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'
```

This is in order to save an image dataset as both a video and an image format.
Any help would be much appreciated.
I've tried a variety of things thus far, like trying to use tk, trying to use both tk and cv2, none of which worked. Use any harassment necessary, I'm aware my code is trash.

Comment: Ok, I give up. Why do you set `size` 14 times when all images are presumably the same size? And why do you loop over 10 values then do the same thing twice more after the loop? Why not do all 12 lots of adding text in one loop?

Comment: In `ph = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imname)`, `imname` is a NumPy array from `imname = cv2.imread(...)`. Use something like `imname = Image.open(...)` to get a proper Pillow `Image` object, which can be passed to `ImageTk.PhotoImage(...)`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell , I'm going to be adding images that aren't the same size in the future, and also for the loops, it's just very messy code.

Comment: @HansHirse, Hey, I modified my code and I now get a different error, this one seems to make no sense whatsoever.  
```imname = PIL.Image.open("~/PycharmProjects/iceSnowComparison/pics/" + '20' + str(i) + '.jpg')
        im1 = imname.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
        ph = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im1)
        cv2.imwrite(("~/PycharmProjects/iceSnowComparison/croppedpics/" + str(year) + '.jpg'),ph)```

And the error is
```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/PycharmProjects/iceSnowComparison/pics/2010.jpg'```

Comment: Nevermind that, I figured it all out